# Bluetooth sharing - Android

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, nxt, lego-mindstorms

I searched the web a long time for a full Bluetooth communication example for android (eclipse) with another Bluetooth device. I found some codes but none of them workd. I'm developing app that will communicate with a lego mindstorms nxt. I will be glad if someone can show me a clear example of a full code with all the steps to perform Bluetooth communication  from beginning to send and receive simple messages like numbers.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you use leJOS to develop your application onto the NXT. So, see that : http://lejos.sourceforge.net/nxt/nxj/tutorial/Communications/Communications.htm

Answer (score 0):

Well you first need to go through some sample examples from the Android developers guide

Refer the developers page for [Bluetooth Communication](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html).

I found [this](http://www.karelbruneel.com/blog/2011/01/steering-wheel/) that would help you start creating your application.

Answer (score 0):

We did similar stuff, except with a microcontroller:

http://code.google.com/p/projectneo/

It's all OpenSource, just browse the code:

http://code.google.com/p/projectneo/source/browse/#svn%2FProjectNEO%2Fbranches%2Fv2

Look at `BluetoothUtils`, `SendService`, `SendJob` and `ReceiveJob`

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code: https://github.com/borismus/android-nxt

You'll find all you need to establish a connection and send data, I've also got another example that a fellow Mindstormer send to me (a project which use of the android compass sensor).

Answer (score 0):

There is an example at the lejos site on sourceforge:

http://lejos.sourceforge.net/nxt/nxj/tutorial/Android/Android.htm

Unfortunately, the referred code must be downloaded somewhere else:

https://github.com/Shawn-in-Tokyo/leJOS-Droid

Important: This example was made fpr lejos 0.8, there were some changes in the API of version 0.9.x, which are quite simple to adapt. I  got it running on leJos 0.9.1 but you could use 0.8 as well.
Contact me if you could make it and how you did it:)